# I'm getting no output in console while running a successfully build project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to capture a biometric sample using WBF (Windows Biometric Framework) in visual studio 2012

This is my main .cpp file:

// FingerPrint.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Stdio.h"
#include "Conio.h"
#include "Winbio.h"
HRESULT CaptureSample();
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT CaptureSample();
    return 0;
}
HRESULT CaptureSample()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle = NULL;
    WINBIO_UNIT_ID unitId = 0;
    WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL rejectDetail = 0;
    PWINBIO_BIR sample = NULL;
    SIZE_T sampleSize = 0;

    // Connect to the system pool. 
    hr = WinBioOpenSession( 
            WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,    // Service provider
            WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         // Pool type
            WINBIO_FLAG_RAW,            // Access: Capture raw data
            NULL,                       // Array of biometric unit IDs
            0,                          // Count of biometric unit IDs
            WINBIO_DB_DEFAULT,          // Default database
            &sessionHandle              // [out] Session handle
            );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioOpenSession failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    // Capture a biometric sample.
    wprintf_s(L"\n Calling WinBioCaptureSample - Swipe sensor...\n");
    hr = WinBioCaptureSample(
            sessionHandle,
            WINBIO_NO_PURPOSE_AVAILABLE,
            WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_RAW,
            &unitId,
            &sample,
            &sampleSize,
            &rejectDetail
            );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (hr == WINBIO_E_BAD_CAPTURE)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n Bad capture; reason: %d\n", rejectDetail);
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioCaptureSample failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        }
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"\n Swipe processed - Unit ID: %d\n", unitId);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Captured %d bytes.\n", sampleSize);


e_Exit:
    if (sample != NULL)
    {
        WinBioFree(sample);
        sample = NULL;
    }

    if (sessionHandle != NULL)
    {
        WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
        sessionHandle = NULL;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"\n Press any key to exit...");
    _getch();

    return hr;
}
```

This is what I get when I build the project :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FingerPrint, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  FingerPrint.cpp
1>  FingerPrint.vcxproj -> C:\Users\hp\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\FingerPrint\Debug\FingerPrint.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is what I get when I debug the file :

```
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\hp\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\FingerPrint\Debug\FingerPrint.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winbio.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\credui.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ScDetour.Dll'. **Cannot find or open the PDB file.**
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Detoured.dll'. **Cannot find or open the PDB file.**
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7600.16385_none_421189da2b7fabfc\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'FingerPrint.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[6216] FingerPrint.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

When I start without debugging: A console window opens saying "press any to exit..." and then if i did that, the window closes..

Comment: I've tidied up your question, in particular formatting the console output using the code device, and removing the request for urgent attention. All questions here are treated equally regardless of their urgency - and often such a request is met with downvotes, so it is best to refrain from marking questions as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT CaptureSample();
    return 0;
}
```

Replace

```
    HRESULT CaptureSample();
```

with

```
    CaptureSample();
```

In your code `HRESULT CaptureSample();` is just forward declaration, and not a function call, so `main` function does not do anything. Debugging the program  you can see, that debugger doesn't stop on this line. Regarding `Cannot find or open the PDB file` messages, just ignore them, you don't need to debug system libraries.

Comment: Thanks a lot..don't know how i missed that...Now i'm getting this error : winbioopensession failed. hr = 0X80070005

Comment: Solved it..Thanks a lot..u r a lifesaver ..thnx 4 the quick reply..don't know how i missed that... one thing more do u know how to convert this into .tiff file...

Comment: If you need to save raw data as tiff file, you can use LibTiffL http://www.libtiff.org/

Comment: There seems to be some comments missing above. How did you get past the 0x80070005 error?